# Automatic log-off scheduled; Windows boots me out after sign-in. How to disable it?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

This has started just a couple hours ago today and I don't know what's doing it.  Some 20 seconds after I sign in, I get a message: "You're about to be signed off". 10 seconds later the PC powers down.

If I execute `shutdown -a` while this message is on screen, it goes away and a notification appears, something like "automated logoff interrupted".

I have checked Task Manager -> Startup, no unknown or suspicious entries. I have also checked Task Scheduler Library, all the non-Windows tasks look legit. Where else to look for the source of this auto-shutdown?

Comment: Can it be that parental controls have been setup, and specifically, logon hours?

Comment: If you look through Event Log messages around the time of the shutdown, you might see messages that help identify the source. For example, when a user initiates the shutdown, Windows records a message that says it shut down on that user's behalf.

Comment: @LPChip: not by me, but perhaps by some malware? Where is that set up?

Comment: How about your parents?

Comment: @LPChip: I bought my mom her own laptop 3 years ago so that she could leave my PC alone :D Furthermore, no one else was even at home at the time when this started happening (and I'm the only person operating this PC). Nor did I install any clearly suspicious software, unless Nvidia gfx driver falls into that category these days.

Comment: Just checking. :) The behavior sounds like parental control software, but if its not that, something else could be the case, a virus, malware or perhaps a hacker.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer of your own so you can mark it as answered. That way, others know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 0):

It was the Corsair Link utility that shut the PC down. It was an unfortunate combination of events, plus a software bug. Long story short, I have configured Corsair Link to shut the PC down with a 5 seconds delay if the liquid cooling pump fails. Link detected it as not running, so it then invoked shutdown, probably by a mere `shutdown` call. That's why there was no Scheduler entry.